# `mvn clean package` is executing my project main

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have this in pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>huru</groupId>
  <artifactId>vertx-start-project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <vertx.version>3.6.0</vertx.version>
    <main.verticle>huru.MainVerticle</main.verticle>
  </properties>


  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-stack-depchain</artifactId>
        <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-auth-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-sync</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-rabbitmq-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-mysql-postgresql-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-jdbc-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.jklingsporn</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-jooq-classic-reactive</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oresoftware</groupId>
      <artifactId>async.0.1</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.101</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-unit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>12</source>
            <target>9</target>
            <useIncrementalCompilation>true</useIncrementalCompilation>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx.api/huru_deps</outputDirectory>
              <!--<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>-->
              <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <formats>zip</formats>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                    <Main-Verticle>${main.verticle}</Main-Verticle>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/services/io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory</resource>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <artifactSet>
              </artifactSet>
              <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>


      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>10</source>
          <target>10</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

for some reason when I run `mvn clean package` it's running my server...I commented out the `exec-maven-plugin`, and it still launches the server, at the end of the package command, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind - it was running my tests as part of the `package` lifecycle, and the junit test started a server with similar output as my actual server! d'oh!